# Calling script in script in crontab -e. Failed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

```
$ script-in-script.sh > /dev/shm/output.txt; works fine.
```

But, if you put the above command line in `script.sh` and add

```
* * * * * script.sh
```

in crontab -e it doesn't work. /dev/shm/output.txt is created anyway but empty.

How can I make it work in `crontab -e`?

PS: `script-in-script.sh` and `script.sh` both are executable.

:script-in-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This Text";
```

:script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
script-in-script.sh > /dev/shm/output.txt;
```

Comment: What is the script? Is there a full path to the script?

Comment: @Pilot6, /home/user58029/bin/script.sh , /home/user58029/bin/script-in-script.sh . #!/bin/bash echo "test string"; very simple.

Comment: So you should add the full path to crontab.

Comment: @Pilot6, full absolute path or full ~ path both don't work with crontab.

Comment: So post the script.

Comment: @Pilot6, I added source code at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add full path to all commands

```
/bin/echo "This text"
```

And also add path to `script-in-script.sh`.

PATH doesn't work in crontabs.

Comment: Oh, my goodness! It works like a charm! Thanks, Pilot6! Wish you richness!

Comment: Well, PATH _does work_ in cronjobs, but is has a default that doesn't allow for much: in my case (without special configuration and as a regular user) the variable contains `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. That's all. So `echo` should work, but `script-in-script.sh` will not without specifying the full name.

Comment: That is correct, but it is useful to always add full path to crontabs.